# .NET Framework, WPF: Cancel Function Raising Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling

I have a function rasing an event

```
public void Delete(bool raiseEvent)
{
       if (raiseEvent)
       {
           RaiseEvent(new EdgeDeletedRoutedEventArgs(DeletedEvent, this));
       }
       ....some other stuff
}
```

I subscribe to that function as follows:

```
Class.Delete += SomethingDeleted;

void SomethingDeleted(object sender, EdgeDeletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        // here i want to cancel the delete function which raises the event
    }  
}
```

How is it possible to cancle the delete function so the "other stuff" is not executed without interrupting my application?

I have tried to throw an exception in SomethingDeleted and catch the exception in Delete but it interrupts my application and id like to keep the application running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `bool Cancel` property to EdgeDeletedRoutedEventArgs (like [CancelEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs?view=net-5.0#remarks) does)

```
public void Delete(bool raiseEvent)
{
       if (raiseEvent)
       {
           var args = new EdgeDeletedRoutedEventArgs(DeletedEvent, this);
           RaiseEvent(args);
           if (args.Cancel) return;
       }
       ....some other stuff
}

void SomethingDeleted(object sender, EdgeDeletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
         e.Cancel = true;
         return;
    }  
}
```

if you don't really need features of RoutedEvent, use regular event (`event EventHandler<EdgeDeletedEventArgs> Delete;`) and inherit EdgeDeletedEventArgs from CancelEventArgs

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i needed!